# Pipe file read stream in Firebase callable function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase **callable function** which is defined like this:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // ...
})
```

What I am trying to do is to pipe a file read stream (reading from Firebase storage) to the response of my **callable function** as I do it in this **http function**:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const file = defaultStorageBucket.file(`/reports/myReport.pdf`);
    const readStream = file.createReadStream();
    readStream.pipe(res)
});
```

Is it possible to achieve that and how? I have noticed that **context** argument contains a **rawRequest** property which contains **Response** but I am not sure how to use it.

My ultimate goal is to start an immediate download of the file on the client of my Firebase app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a good use case for a callable function.  Callable functions always return JSON type data, and that data is automatically serialized by the function using the value you return from it.  Piping data is not supported.  If you really do want to return the contents of some arbitrary file from a callable function, you would have to read the entire contents of the file in memory, encode it as a string, put that string into a JavaScript object, and return the object.  This is really not what callable functions are intended to to do - you are better off sticking to a regular HTTP type function in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe data in regular HTTP firebase functions?

Comment: Pray tell, is it a good use case for a Storage-triggered Cloud Functions? How would one go about validating uploads, at a byte level? How would one go about manipulating Storage files at a byte level?